# why data not displaying from the data base while clicking on next page using pagination in codeigniter php

Tags: php, html, xampp, codeigniter-3

i'm using pagination in codeigniter and displaying data on my view.
i have receiving all the database value on my view file
and also next page link are appearing
while im trying to click on the next page then data which is displaying is not changing. while clicking on the next page so data is not changing
i just want while i click on next page then data should change.
here is my code.
here is my controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
      $this->load->library('table');

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->database(); //load library database
        $this->load->model('pagtodmodel/paginationtodaymodel');

}

public function index($offset=0){

  $config['total_rows'] = $this->paginationtodaymodel->totalInfo();

  $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/paginationtoday/Paginationtodaycontroller/test";
  $config['per_page'] = 1;
  $config['uri_segment'] = '3';

  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';

  $config['first_link'] = '« First';
  $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
  $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['last_link'] = 'Last »';
  $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
  $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['next_link'] = 'Next →';
  $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
  $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['prev_link'] = '← Previous';
  $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
  $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

  $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
  $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


  $this->pagination->initialize($config);


  $query = $this->paginationtodaymodel->getInfo($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2));

  $data['mydata'] = null;

  if($query){
   $data['mydata'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('pagtodview/paginationtoday',$data);
}
public function test($page){
    $page++;

      print_r($page);
      $config['total_rows'] = $this->paginationtodaymodel->totalInfo();

      $config['base_url'] = base_url()."index.php/paginationtoday/Paginationtodaycontroller/test";
      $config['per_page'] = 1;
      $config['uri_segment'] = '3';

      $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
      $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';

      $config['first_link'] = '« First';
      $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
      $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

      $config['last_link'] = 'Last »';
      $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
      $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

      $config['next_link'] = 'Next →';
      $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
      $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

      $config['prev_link'] = '← Previous';
      $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
      $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

      $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
      $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

      $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
      $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


      $this->pagination->initialize($config);


      $query = $this->paginationtodaymodel->getInfo($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2));

      $data['mydata'] = null;

      if($query){
       $data['mydata'] =  $query;
      }

      $this->load->view('pagtodview/paginationtoday',$data);
    }
```

model

```
   <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Paginationtodaymodel extends CI_Model {
function MovieModel(){
parent::Model();
}
function getInfo($limit=null,$offset=NULL){
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->from('getproductvalues');
$this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
function totalInfo(){
return $this->db->count_all_results('getproductvalues');
}
}
```

please checkout where im doing wrong in my code.
data is receiving from the database nicely and also displaying
but whenever i'm clicking on the next page then data is not changing
please check this code where i have done wrong in my code.

Comment: show your view file !

Comment: thanks for comment brother @M.Alim it is solved now. thank you